# Inclusion of $n$-skeleton induces surjection of cohomology rings

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Suppose $X$ is a CW complex and $X_n$ its $n$-skeleton, the cohomology ring $H^*(X)$ of $X$ is defined to be the direct sum of its cohomology groups with multiplication as cup product. Does the inclusion $i:X_n\rightarrowtail X$ induce surjection of the cohomology rings 
$i^*:H^*(X)\to H^*(X_n)$ ?  I can see that it is isomorphism for $i^k:H^k(X)\to H^k(X_n)$ with $k<n$ and $H^k(X_n)=0$ for $k>n$. But how can I determine whether $i^n:H^n(X)\to H^n(X_n)$ is surjective?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The inclusion $S^1 \rightarrow S^\infty$ cannot induce a surjection since $S^\infty$ is contractible.

Comment: How about X is the infinite real projective space?

Comment: If you write out the cellular cochain complex you can probably compute it directly. If you are interested generally if the inclusion induces surjections, I think what you wan to look up is obstruction theory. By the characterization of cohomology as maps into Eilenberg-MacLane spaces, your question comes down to if any map $X^{n-1} \rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z},n-1)$ can be extended to a map $X^n \rightarrow K(\mathbb{Z},n-1)$ which is what obstruction theory deals with. As well, if you are interested in the question for arbitrary coefficients, you just replace $\mathbb{Z}$ with your group.

Comment: If I calculate the cohomology group directly for $\mathbb{R} P^n\to \mathbb{R} P^{\infty}$, then the cohomology group in $n$ for $n$ odd is not surjective, is this right? I just would like to check this as someone told me the inclusion of real projective space induces surjection of cohomology rings.

Comment: Yes, because in odd dimensions there is a copy of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the cohomology of $\mathbb{R}P^n$.